# Peace Lily: Are these spores or eggs?

Tags: identification, houseplants, diagnosis, plant-care, peace-lily

So i have thise peace lily that has been recently been getting brown spots all over the leaves and today i decided to take a closer look at the whole plant and see if i can find anything immediately wrong with it.

After a closer look i saw this:
[image: peace lily]

Are they eggs? Fungus spores? Any help would be super appreciated!

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The yellow balls? Those are just little sacks of fertilizer. When you water the plant, the casing should break and release the fertilizer. Dig one out and run it under some water and squeeze and it'll pop.

Sounds like you might just be having problems with light for your peace lily.